# Remove hash(#) in URL Angular 11

Tags: angular, typescript, web, angular11

I want to remove the # from the URL, but when I remove it, there will be a problem when I deploy it to the server. When the page is refreshed, will get a status of 404.

example

https: // a / user / (works)

https: // a / user / 1 (Not working)

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
    @NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  providers: [
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy} 
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**app.module.ts**

```
......
providers: [ Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}]
```

Please advise me what should I do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PathLocationStrategy is the default location strategy of Angular Routing, It should work and resolve your hash(#) problem.

There is no error in your code, double check below points

1. `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true }) //use Hash should not be there`
2. providers: [
   // Below line is optional as default LocationStrategy is PathLocationStrategy
   {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}
   ]

If you are only facing issue in server  when deployed, Please check the entry point configuration in the server. It should be index.html file.

**NOTE**: when using PathLocationStrategy you need to configure your web server to serve index.html (app's entry point) for all requested locations.

Also check the `<base href="/">` in index.html and at the backend server, we must render the index.html file according to path.